# Magento Sage 50 Integration

Tags: magento-community, integrate

I'm looking for an integration solution between Magento CE and Sage 50 Quantum Canadian Edition. I see there are solutions for the US version of Sage but cannot seem to find any affordable solutions for the Canadian edition. Has anyone worked with integrating Magento with Sage 50 Canadian Edition before and have any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why you want for solution only for Canadian version? Maybe you can check [Sage 100 standard](https://iigservices.com/products/sage-100-standard/) from USA? We have used that few months ago and connected that with our Magento CE with their extension without any problem. I can share my experience in PM with you if you want.